# How to access params or history.state in beforeEnter of routes in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I use vue.js.

I want to prevent to access a page without some value(questionNo) when user type url('/question') direct and click the button but there is no value.

**main.vue**

```js
function buttonClickFunc(Num) {
  return route.push({
    name: 'question',
    state: { questionNo: Num }
  })
};
```

**router.js**

```js
// ...
{
  path: '/question',
  name: 'question',
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if(!history.state.questionNo) { // there is no questionNo
      next('/main');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

I don't use `query` instead `state` when using router.push.

Because the url need to be '/question' not 'question=?questionNo=14'.

And If using `params`, there is a [Vue Router warn] msg in console tools.
[warn link](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22)

There is the way to check questionNo exist before router push but it can't prevent to typing url directly.

Answer (score 2):

We change history.state.questionNo => to.params.questionNo in the beforeEnter hook because when you use history.state to access the questionNo value, you are relying on the browser's history.state object, which may not always be available.

When you use route parameters, the parameter values are included in the URL, and they can be easily accessed using to.params. This makes it more reliable to check for the existence of the questionNo value.

**main.vue**

```html
function buttonClickFunc(Num) {
  return route.push({
    name: 'question',
    params: { question: Num }
  })
};
```

**route.js**

```html
{
  path: '/question/:questionNo',
  name: 'question',
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if(!to.params.questionNo) { // there is no questionNo
      next('/main');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: "the parameter values are included in the URL" OP explicitly says they're not using query / URL params

Comment: The route parameters, such as questionNo, are included directly in the URL path, not as query parameters.

Comment: Correct - part of the URL. Which the OP does not want, and which would be inappropriate for many kinds of data in any case.

Comment: Yes. I understand your concern. It's right.